# How to set the limit to display records in table cell using mysql and php?

Tags: php, mysql

Display records in a table cell with limit using php and mysql.

Table Cells:4 and display record content length 5

Output:

```
1  6   11  16 
2  7   12  17    ---------> Row 1
3  8   13  18
4  9   14  19 
5  10  15  20 

21  26   31  36 
22  27   32  37  ---------> Row 2
23  28   33  
24  29   34  
25  30   35
```

can any one help me to display the records in this ormat using php.

Thanks.

Comment: **E_PARSE_ERROR** //can not even guess what means your question. be more verbose

Comment: I think the OP wants to display up to 20 records in a 4x5 grid, down then over.

Answer (score 3):

Try this :)

```
<?php
$a = array ("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20");  
echo '<table>';
echo '<tr><td>';
$columns = 4;   // how many columns you want.
$break = ceil(count($a)/$columns);
for($i=0;$i<=count($a);$i++)
{
    if($i%$break==0)
    {
        echo "</td><td>";
    }
    echo '<a>'.$a[$i].'</a></br>';
}
echo '</td></tr>';
echo '</table>';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is modular, but may break with suboptimal HTML content. However, the re-usable part of this problem (IMO) is the math problem, which the first block of code addresses.

```
define('TABLE_COLS', 4);
define('TABLE_ROWS', 5);
define('TABLE_CELLS', TABLE_COLS * TABLE_DIMENSIONS);

foreach ($results as $k => $contents){
    $i = $k-1; // because 1-indexing is required by the OP
    $grid_num = $i / TABLE_CELLS;
    $row = $i % TABLE_ROWS;
    $col = $i / TABLE_ROWS;
    $grids[$grid_num][$row][$col] = $contents;
}
```

For verifying results only! We should be using DOMDocument to insert DOM elements, not concatenated echos.

```
foreach ($grids as $grid){
    print_grid($grid);
}

function print_grid($grid){
    echo '<table>';
    foreach ($grid as $row){
        print_row($row);
    }
    echo '</table>';
}

function print_row($row){
    echo '<tr>';
    foreach ($row as $cell){
        print_cell($cell);
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}

function print_cell($cell){
    echo '<td>'.$cell.'</td>';
}
```