# print number vertically and grouping it

Tags: php

I am trying to print number vertically and it must be in group

here is my code

```
$nums = 105;
$rows = 8;
$col = floor($nums / $rows);
$group = floor($col / 3);
$count = 0;
for ($g = 0; $g <= $group; $g++) {
    echo "<div class='group'>";
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $rows; $i++) {
        for ($j = $i; $j <= 24; $j = $j + $rows) {
            $count++;
            if($count>$nums){
                break;
        }
            echo "<div class='fleft'>$count</div>";
        }
        echo "<div class='clear'></div>";
    }
    echo "</div>";
}
```

out of above

[image]

but i want output like for the first column

[image]

and next group number will start from where first group number end. in this case next group start from 25

please ask if any doubt

Comment: Possibly http://stackoverflow.com/q/2221476/760211 can help

Comment: i can do that if have to display in one group only but not able to do in groups

Comment: I hope this could help You: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18844108/how-to-set-the-limit-to-display-records-in-table-cell-using-mysql-and-php/18844214#18844214

Comment: i made a soln by altering ur code .. hope that helps ...postng it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$nums = 105;
$rows = 8;
$colsize = 3;

$col = floor($nums / $rows);
$group = floor($col / $colsize);
$count = 0;
$groupsize = $rows * $colsize;
for ($g = 0; $g <= $group; $g++) {
    echo "<div class='group'>";

    $modulo = 0;
    $correction = 0;
    $rest = $nums - $count;
    if ($rest < $groupsize) {
        $empty = $groupsize - $rest;
        $correction = floor($empty / $colsize);
        $modulo = $empty % $colsize;
    }
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $rows; $i++) {
        $colind = 0;
        for ($j = $i; $j <= $groupsize; $j = $j + $rows) { 
            $count++;
            if ($count > $nums) {
                break;
            }
            $val = $j + ($g * $groupsize);

            $val -= $colind * $correction;
            $modcor = $colind - ($colsize - $modulo);
            if ( $modcor > 0 ) {
                $val -= $modcor;
            }
            echo "<div class='fleft'>" . $val . "</div>";
            $colind++;
        }
        echo "<div class='clear'></div>";
    }
    echo "</div>";
}
```

This works:

[image]

Also, you can change number of digits, columns or size of column

Comment: Problem with this : put $nums=31, 30 is missing and it should print up to 31. this is printing to 32. by the way this is good . i am voting up for logic

Answer (score 0):

```
for($group = 0; $group < 3; $group++){
    for($row =1 ; $row <= 8; $row++){
        for($col = 0; $col <= 2; $col++){
            echo ($group*24)+ $row + 8 * $col; echo " ";
        }
        echo "\n";
    }
}
```

This code will print the number in the requested format. You need to modify according to your need.

Comment: this is not printing up to number (105)

Comment: This code won't print the number exactly you want. You need to change the code according to your need. I have given you the logic of printing numbers in group of 8*3

Answer (score 0):

may be i am  mad , made a simple alter .... **try this**

```
$nums = 105;
$rows = 8;
$col = floor($nums / $rows);
$group = floor($col / 3);
$count = 0;
$letCounter=0;  //added a counter

for ($g = 0; $g <= $group; $g++) {

    echo "<div class='group'>";
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $rows; $i++) {
        $letCounter=0; //reset counter on each loop
        for ($j = $i; $j <= 24; $j = $j + $rows) 
        {
         $count++;
         if($count>$nums)
         {break;}
        //made an alter  in the below line , some math :)
         echo "<div class='fleft'>".($letCounter++ * $rows +$i)."</div>";  
        }
        echo "<div class='clear'></div>";
    }
    echo "</div>";
}
```

**Thanks !**

Comment: @BhavikPatel yep....any problm wth u? 1
9
17
2
10
18
3
11
19
4
12
20
5
13
21
6
14
22
7
15
23
8
16
24
1
9
17
2
10
18
3
11

Comment: it's repeating  not increasing after 24

Answer (score 0):

This May work

```
$nums = 105;
$rows = 8;
$col = floor($nums / $rows);
$group = floor($col / 3);
$count = 0;
$flag = true;
for($c=1;$c<=$col;$c++)
{

        if($c%$group== 1)
        {
            echo "Group Start";
            $flag = false;
        }
        for ($i = 1; $i <= $rows; $i++) {
                $count++;
                echo "<div class='fleft'>$count</div>";

            echo "<div class='clear'></div>";

        }
        echo "Line End";
        if($c%$group == 2&& $flag)// Check here for your requirement        
            echo "Group End </br>";
        $flag = true;

}
```